# Decrease space in all 4 directions of textfield

Tags: html, css

I want to decrease the extra space outside the textfield on all 4 sides.

Now it's displaying like

[image]

But I want it to look like below

[image]

```css
.wk_row_view td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: HTML is where exactly?

Comment: Because of the height of the second cell you can't achieve this, you will also need to reduce the content in the second cell

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Dale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reduce the padding.

```css
.wk_row_view td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;                  /* made it 2 px */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: space reduced in left & right, but in top & bottom its still there. also first column width increased very much

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe the top and bottom space is because of your second column has a image and text which is taking space and all other cells in the row will have the same height

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe also the credentials you provided is not working

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe no buddy I tried 10 times and no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112499/discussion-between-nsdlfefinedieicbe-and-reddy).

Comment: can you please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269248/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe sorry buddy never worked with paypal stuff

Comment: sorrry. for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center/37546253?noredirect=1#comment62582347_37546253

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe I think you have already fixed the issue. I saw the link and seems like you have already got this working as expected